# Is "a man after my own heart" for Jesee or David?

Tags: nouns

In the following sentence:

> I have found David son of Jesse, a man after my own heart; he will do everything I want him to do.

Is "a man after my own heart" for Jesse, or for David? From the context, I know it's for David, but "a man after my own heart" sits closer to Jesse than David, so is it ambiguous from syntax?

Comment: "David son of Jesse" is one person. That should set things at rest.

Comment: There's a point where a phrase like "son of Jesse" is no longer a descriptive phrase and becomes more of an epithet/title/surname, e.g. Irish "O'Donnell" or Israeli "Ben something". In such cases, where it functions as an epithet (patronymic), it's clear that you're referring to the name as a whole ("David son of Jesse") and not Jesse or Donnell (Domhail). Is this happening here? Is "David son of Jesse" a standard formulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Son of Jesse" is an example of a [patronymic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic). In ancient times, "family names" weren't really a thing; rather you'd distinguish one "David" (for example) from all the others by specifying where he was from or who his father was.

In some cases, you'd be correct that the syntax is ambiguous, and you could conceivably be referring to someone whose father was "a man after my own heart". However, in [this case](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2013%3A22&version=KJV) there is almost no ambiguity - Paul is giving an abbreviated history of Israel, and "David son of Jesse" would be immediately recognized by his audience as Israel's most famous king. There's very little chance any of them would think he's referring to Jesse.